# Convert C++ datastructure into intelligible HDF5 dataset (Vector of Pairs)

Tags: python, c++, hdf5

I have the following datastructure in C++:

```
std::vector<std::pair<boost::geometry::model::point<double, 3, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>, std::vector<double>>>
```

In English, this represents a bunch of spacial locations, each of which is coupled to a metadata vector of the same length.

I need help constructing an elegant representation of this datastructure as an HDF5 dataset.

My first attempt was to use (in Python, as a mockup)

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File('foo.h5', 'w')
f.create_dataset('locations_and_metadata', (num_locations, metadata_len + 3))
```

and simply interpret the first three elements in the dataset as the coordinates, but this is ugly and nonintuitive. In particular, I can't add units as an attribute to the spacial location, which decreases the 'self-describing' nature of the HDF5 file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was compound datatypes, see [here](https://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/Py/h5_compound.py) for an example.

To solve this particular problem, I used:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import h5py
import numpy

output = h5py.File('foo.h5', 'w')

len = 50

x0 = 1.23
y0 = 2.25
z0 = 7.84

a0 = numpy.random.uniform(size=len)

x1 = 2.34;
y1 = 4.38;
z1 = 7.25;

a1 = numpy.random.uniform(size=len)

comp_type = numpy.dtype([('x', numpy.float64), ('y', numpy.float64), ('z', numpy.float64), ('trace', (numpy.dtype('<d'), len))])
g = output.create_dataset('my_type', (2,), comp_type)
data = numpy.array([(x0, y0, z0, a0), (x1, y1, z1, a1)], dtype=comp_type)
g[...] = data

output.close()
```

The code in C++ was a bit more complicated; essentially I had to create a contiguous array of doubles (as `std::pair` is not guaranteed to be contiguous in RAM), but looking at the documentation for `H5::CompType` should get you where you need to go. The C++ example is [here](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/compound_8cpp-example.html).